# Knowing when a ModalPopupExtender user control has closed

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have created a usercontrol (.ascx) for use in my asp.net website (not mvc). The control has a few text boxes and allows the user to enter a new customer. It has two buttons, one to add the customer and one to cancel the control. I call display the control by using a “ModalPopupExtender “ with the code shown below:

This is in an updatePanel:

```
<asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender2" runat="server" TargetControlID="hiddenButton"
 PopupControlID="Panel3" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" DropShadow="true"/>
```

Here is the Panel3 markup:

```
<asp:Panel ID="Panel3" runat="server" Style="display: none" CssClass="modalPopup" Width="100%" Height="100%">
    <uc3:CustomerForm  runat="server" ID="CustomerForm1" ParentUpdatePanel="UpdatePanel1" ErrorDisplayControl="lblErrorMessage"/>
</asp:Panel>
```

When I click a button on the main page the code behind calls:

```
ModalPopupExtender2.Show();
```

This shows my control and when I add a new customer the database is updated so this side of things works fine. What I need to do is enhance the code so that when a customer is added and the usercontrol closes, the customer dropdownlist on the main page is loaded with the updated customer list and the customer that the user enter is selected. The dropdownlist is databound so my question is, how do I know when my usercontrol has been closed so I can work out if a new customer has been added and then re databind my list and select the correct item? Working with asp.net and javascript is not an area I have a lot of skill in so please forgive if I have used the wrong terminology.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution to my problem. In my usercontrol, after a new customer has been added I call:

```
RaiseBubbleEvent(this, new CustomerArgs {OrganisationId = organisationId});
```

In the calling page’s code behind I listen for the bubble event:

```
protected override bool OnBubbleEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (sender is CustomerForm && e is CustomerArgs)
    {
        _organisationID = (e as CustomerArgs).OrganisationId.ToString();
        DoOrganisationListDataBind();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

This works fine for what I’m after. Not sure if this is a good way to do it but it works.